# Deleting rows from csv based on input file

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a daily process which runs on Linux that returns a set of failed updated users, and need to delete these bad rows from the large user csv for importation into a database.

My output file contains the USER_ID for each failed user.
I'm trying to create an updated file with these removed.
I have reviewed the multitude of examples available, but none seem to work correctly. I've included a sample of the error file and the user file.
The first row is a header, and should be ignored

My error file:

```
"USER_ID"
"CA781558"
"LN764767"
```

My user file:

```
"USER_ID","FIRSTNAME","LASTNAME","LAST_ACTIVITY","GROUD_UID"
"CA781558","Dani","Roper","2015-07-17 19:47:21","CF93DF0A-BD23AF87D20A"
"BT055163","Alexis","Richardo","2016-04-19 21:23:08","CB71F91E-7E638292ABD5"
"LN764767","Peter","Rajosz","2016-03-18 11:59:29","973C4AD2-63BA12BB91CD"
"TN479717","Jerry","Alindos","2015-06-12 07:37:56","1DA745BA-71CB88AA91EA"
"FR915163","Alexis","Richardo","2016-04-19 21:23:08","DBA8B91E-7A6B8292ABD5"
"GB135767","Peter","Rajosz","2016-03-18 11:59:29","AE3C4AD2-63BA181B91CD"
"SG839717","Jerry","Alindos","2015-06-12 07:37:56","1BA746BA-71CB88AA91EA"
```

Expected Output:

```
"USER_ID","FIRSTNAME","LASTNAME","LAST_ACTIVITY","GROUD_UID"
"BT055163","Alexis","Richardo","2016-04-19 21:23:08","CB71F91E-7E638292ABD5"
"TN479717","Jerry","Alindos","2015-06-12 07:37:56","1DA745BA-71CB88AA91EA"
"FR915163","Alexis","Richardo","2016-04-19 21:23:08","DBA8B91E-7A6B8292ABD5"
"GB135767","Peter","Rajosz","2016-03-18 11:59:29","AE3C4AD2-63BA181B91CD"
"SG839717","Jerry","Alindos","2015-06-12 07:37:56","1BA746BA-71CB88AA91EA"
```

Can you help?  Thank you in advance

Comment: **I have reviewed the multitude of examples available** Have you really tried anything?

Comment: My apologies. I was up until the wee hours last night trying to find a solution and coming up blank. My input and output row count stayed the same.
Turns out, somewhere along the line I made a mistake and overwrote my master list with the update.  From that point, my output matched the input. Apologies for the question.  Feel free to delete.

 awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' error.csv user.csv > output.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{del[$1]; next} FNR==1 || !($1 in del)' err.txt file.txt

"USER_ID","FIRSTNAME","LASTNAME","LAST_ACTIVITY","GROUD_UID"
"BT055163","Alexis","Richardo","2016-04-19 21:23:08","CB71F91E-7E638292ABD5"
"TN479717","Jerry","Alindos","2015-06-12 07:37:56","1DA745BA-71CB88AA91EA"
"FR915163","Alexis","Richardo","2016-04-19 21:23:08","DBA8B91E-7A6B8292ABD5"
"GB135767","Peter","Rajosz","2016-03-18 11:59:29","AE3C4AD2-63BA181B91CD"
"SG839717","Jerry","Alindos","2015-06-12 07:37:56","1BA746BA-71CB88AA91EA"
```